# As about - I was reading an article in that magazine. It was as about the new government policies

Tags: word-usage

I know this usage

> With prepositions, as has the general sense of as far as, so far as, and thus restricts or specially defines the reference of the preposition; e.g. as against, as between. as anent, as concerning, as for, {as to}, as touching (Fr. quant à), have all the sense of ‘as it regards, so far as it concerns, with respect or reference to.’ [Source - Oxford]

And from this usage note I am pretty sure that one can construct ***"as about"***, just like ***"as to"*** or ***"as against"***.

So I wrote a sentence using ***"as about"***, and I think I am right about it. Here is this sentence -

> I was reading an article in that magazine. It was **as about** the new government policies.

I searched Google, and found the following sentence -

> [Questions lots of kids as about their skin, hair, and nails.](http://www.aad.org/dermatology-a-to-z/for-kids/common-questions)

But I failed to find out any other examples from web. So I guess it's very rare.

Please comment on this type of usage of ***"as about"***

Comment: That example contains a typo: "Questions lots of kids **ask** about their skin, hair, and nails."

Comment: @snailplane Ah, I see... But what about the sentence above that I wrote, that includes ***as about***?

Comment: It doesn't *look* grammatical to me… What does it mean?

Comment: @snailplane Actually I was trying to make words like "as to", "as against". And so I made "as about".

Comment: @Man_From_India we usually try to *avoid* ambiguity, not to introduce! *I was reading an article in that magazine. It was about the new government policies -short, sweet and understandable!*

Comment: I think, for perhaps all except "so as to", I'd understand "as to", "as against", and "as about", as two words: "as" and "to" or "against" or "about".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I (a native American English speaker) know, there is no such phrase as *as about*.

I think the most useful way to understand the other "as" phrases is just to think of them as set idioms that can't be decomposed any further. That's pretty much how native speakers treat them. They also have a formal bent to them, and are more commonly seen in public speeches and legal or business documents than in other kinds of writing or speech.